# Parsing numbers with a comma decimal separator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation

I used this function to check if a value is a number:

```
function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

My program need to work with German values. We use a comma as the decimal separator instead of a dot, so this function doesn't work.

I tried to do this:

```
n.replace(",",".")
```

But it also doesn't seem to work. The exact function I tried to use is:

```
function isNumber(n) {
    n=n.replace(",",".");
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

The number looks like this `9.000,28` instead of the usual `9,000.28` if my statement wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Are there `.`s when the number is greater than 999?

Comment: Keep in mind that `replace` *returns* a new string.

Comment: Please post the full code using `replace`.  That should be sufficient so there must be something else wrong.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to replace (remove) the dots first in the thousands separator, then take care of the decimal:

```
function isNumber(n) {
    'use strict';
    n = n.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.');
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Comment: Fails with `111.222.3333,44`.  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8nAX/1/).  `.replace` only replaces the first match unless you have a global regular expression. *edit: whoops messed up the input string*

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Thanks, I updated my code.. not really good with regular expressions, does that seem right to you?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly right (I had it wrong in my original fiddle)

Comment: This solution works for "nice" users but validation needs to work even for "bad" users. If you have the following (for example) this passes when it shouldn't: var testNumber = "10.0.0,000";

Answer (score 30):

```
var number = parseFloat(obj.value.replace(",",""));
```

You'll probably also want this to go the other way...

```
obj.value = number.toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 2});
```

Comment: With this answer 123,4 gives you 1234 for the parse, and 1234.00 for the localisation. It's not answering the question, which is parsing comma decimal separators.

Comment: Using `toLocaleString` is the best option for me, thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I believe the best way of doing this is simply using the toLocaleString method. 
For instance, I live in Brazil, here we have comma as decimal separator. Then I can do:

```
var number = 10.01;
console.log(number)
// log: 10.01

console.log(number.toLocaleString("pt-BR"));
// log: 10,01
```