# How to Compute number with Comma (,)

Tags: javascript, html

I have js code that you can input numbers(without comma) and compute.

My js script compute properly, but main problem is when I input number with comma(,) I have error/my formula is not working.

Here's my snippet below.

***Note: I put default value with comma and my formula is not wot working.***
***But when you put without comma it's working***

Thankyou!

```js
  
  function change() {
        var loanamount_total = $("#loanamount").val();
        var loanintrest = $("#loanintrest").val();
        var period = $("#period").val();
        var per_year = $("#per_year").val();
        var downpayment_percent = $("#downpayment").val();
        var downpayment = (Number(downpayment_percent) * Number(loanamount_total)) / 100;

        var loanamount = Number(loanamount_total) - Number(downpayment);
        var intrest = (loanintrest / 100) / 12;
        
    
        
        var permonth = calculate(loanamount , Number(period) * 12 );
        var total_amount = permonth * Number(period) * 12;
        
        var total_intrest =  total_amount - loanamount;
        $("#permonth").text("AED" + permonth);
        $("#downpament_a").text("AED" + downpayment.toFixed(2));
        $("#loanamount_total").text("AED" + Number(loanamount_total).toFixed(2));
        $("#total_interest").text("AED" + total_intrest.toFixed(2));
        $("#total_amount").text("AED" + total_amount.toFixed(2));
        
        var total_intrest_percent = (Number(total_intrest) * 100) / Number(total_amount);
        var total_amount_precent = (Number(loanamount) * 100) / Number(total_amount);
        
        var left_amount = Number(total_amount);
        var loanamount_left = Number(loanamount);
        $( "#tbody" ).html("");
        for(var i=1; i <= Number(period) * 12; i++) { 
            var intrest_l = intrest * loanamount_left;
            left_amount = left_amount - permonth;
            var principle = permonth - intrest_l;
            loanamount_left = loanamount_left - principle;
                $( "#tbody" ).append( "<tr style='background-color: #FBFCFF;border-top: dotted #DEEEFE 1px;'><td style='padding:5px'> "+ i +" </td><td> AED"+ permonth  +" </td> <td>AED" + principle.toFixed(2) +" </td><td>AED" + intrest_l.toFixed(2)  + "</td>  <td> AED"+ left_amount.toFixed(2) +" </td></tr>" );
        }
  
  
    }
 
 
 

 

    $("body").on("keyup", "#downpayment , #loanintrest , #loanamount , #period, #per_year", function () {
        change();
    });

    $(function () {
        change();
    });
 
 
  function calculate(amount , term)
  {
   // Standard Mortgage Formula:
   // M = P[i(1+i)n] / [(1+i)n - 1]
   // x = (1+i)n

   var P = amount;
   var i = ($('#loanintrest').val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '') / 100) / 12;
   var n = term;
   var x = Math.pow((1 + i ), n);
   var M = ( P * ((i * x) / (x - 1)) ).toFixed(2);
   return M;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default panel-sidebar-1 filter-checkbox-container">  
    <div class="panel-heading"><h3><?php _l('Mortgage'); ?></h3></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
       
        <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

        <div class="form-group mamount"> 
            <label for="loanamount" class="col-md-12 control-label">{lang_mort_property_price}</label>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="input-group"> 
                    <input   value="4,000" name="loanamount" id="loanamount" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">AED</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--form group ammount end-->

        <div class="form-group mamount"> 
            <label for="loanamount" class="col-md-12 control-label">{lang_mort_downpay}</label>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="input-group"> 
                    <input type="number" value="20" name="downpayment" id="downpayment" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--form group ammount end-->

        <div class="form-group mamount"> 
            <label for="loanamount" class="col-md-12 control-label">{lang_mort_interest}</label>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="input-group"> 
                    <input type="number" value="5" name="loanintrest" id="loanintrest" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--form group ammount end-->

        <div class="form-group mamount"> 
            <label for="loanamount" class="col-md-12 control-label">{lang_mort_year}</label>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="input-group"> 
                    <input type="number" value="5" name="period" id="period" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Year</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--form group ammount end-->
        </div><!--panel body end-->

</br>
 <!-- Chart Area-->
<div class="accordion" id="accordionArea">
 <div class="accordion-group panel">
    <!--result-->
        <div class="accordion-heading accordionize"> <a class="accordion-toggle active" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionArea" href="#mortresult"><i class="fa fa-calculator"></i> Result <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> </a> </div>
            <div id="mortresult" class="accordion-body in collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner"> 
                <p> {lang_mort_month} : <strong > <span style="float:right" id="permonth"> 0 </span> </strong> </p> 
          <p> {lang_mort_downpay} :<strong> <span style="float:right" id="downpament_a"> 0 </span> </strong> </p>
          <p> {lang_mort_tamount} :<strong> <span style="float:right" id="loanamount_total"> 0 </span> </strong> </p>
          <p> {lang_mort_tinterest} :<strong> <span style="float:right" id="total_interest"> 0 </span> </strong> </p>
          <p> {lang_mort_tpay} :<strong> <span style="float:right" id="total_amount"> 0 </span> </strong> </p>
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#disclaimer">{lang_mort_disclaimer}</a>
              <div class="modal fade" id="disclaimer" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <p><font color="red">Warning</font> - The information provided by this tool is for guidance, and does not include all of the details you need to choose a mortgage. Figures given by this calculator do not constitute an offer to lend to you.</p>

     <p>This calculator is designed to give you an indication of the amount that we may be able to lend you on a capital repayment basis. The results shown above are estimates and should be used as guide only. The maximum we would consider lending will depend on your individual situation, the property you are purchasing (e.g. new build), the loan you choose and the amount you wish to borrow. The actual amount will depend on checks that we subsequently undertake and further fees and charges may apply.</p>
     </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default inverted" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
          </div><!--inner end-->
            </div><!--accordion body end-->
        <!--chart-->
        <!--
        <div class="accordion-heading accordionize"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionArea" href="#mortchart"><i class="fa  fa-pie-chart"></i> View Chart <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> </a> </div>
            <div id="mortchart" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner"> 
              <div id="hightcart_container" style=""></div>
          </div>
            </div>-->
            <!--accordion body end-->

<!--
<div class="accordion-heading accordionize"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#monthg" href="#mortmonthly"> Monthly Payment Guide  </a> </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="monthg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">   <table style="width:100%" id="printTable"> 
 <thead style="background:#DEEEFE;width:100%;"> 
 <tr style="width:100%"> 
  <td style=" width:20%">  Month </td> 
  <td style=" width:20%" > Per/Month </td> 
  <td style=" width:20%" > Principle </td> 
  <td style=" width:20%" > Interest </td> 
  <td style=" width:20%"> Balance </td> 
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="tbody"> 
 
 </tbody>
 <thead style="background:#DEEEFE;width:100%;"> 
 <tr style="width:100%"> 
  <td style=" width:20%">  Month </td> 
  <td style=" width:20%" > Per/Month </td> 
  <td style=" width:20%" > Principle </td> 
  <td style=" width:20%" > Interest </td> 
  <td style=" width:20%"> Balance </td> 
 </tr>
 </thead>
 </table> </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default inverted" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

-->
    </div><!--accordion end-->
</div><!--accordion end-->

    
    </div><!--panel panel end-->
```

Comment: You will have to replace the commas while calculating. Try `Number(value.replace(/,/g, ''))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing numbers with a comma decimal separator in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405178/parsing-numbers-with-a-comma-decimal-separator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace all *comma*s from the input value before calculation

```
var loanamount_total = $("#loanamount").val().replace(/,/g, "");
```

**Demo**

```js
function change() {
        var loanamount_total = $("#loanamount").val().replace(/,/g, "");
        var loanintrest = $("#loanintrest").val();
        var period = $("#period").val();
        var per_year = $("#per_year").val();
        var downpayment_percent = $("#downpayment").val();
        var downpayment = (Number(downpayment_percent) * Number(loanamount_total)) / 100;

        var loanamount = Number(loanamount_total) - Number(downpayment);
        var intrest = (loanintrest / 100) / 12;
        
    
        
        var permonth = calculate(loanamount , Number(period) * 12 );
        var total_amount = permonth * Number(period) * 12;
        
        var total_intrest =  total_amount - loanamount;
        $("#permonth").text("AED" + permonth);
        $("#downpament_a").text("AED" + downpayment.toFixed(2));
        $("#loanamount_total").text("AED" + Number(loanamount_total).toFixed(2));
        $("#total_interest").text("AED" + total_intrest.toFixed(2));
        $("#total_amount").text("AED" + total_amount.toFixed(2));
        
        var total_intrest_percent = (Number(total_intrest) * 100) / Number(total_amount);
        var total_amount_precent = (Number(loanamount) * 100) / Number(total_amount);
        
        var left_amount = Number(total_amount);
        var loanamount_left = Number(loanamount);
        $( "#tbody" ).html("");
        for(var i=1; i <= Number(period) * 12; i++) { 
            var intrest_l = intrest * loanamount_left;
            left_amount = left_amount - permonth;
            var principle = permonth - intrest_l;
            loanamount_left = loanamount_left - principle;
                $( "#tbody" ).append( "<tr style='background-color: #FBFCFF;border-top: dotted #DEEEFE 1px;'><td style='padding:5px'> "+ i +" </td><td> AED"+ permonth  +" </td> <td>AED" + principle.toFixed(2) +" </td><td>AED" + intrest_l.toFixed(2)  + "</td>  <td> AED"+ left_amount.toFixed(2) +" </td></tr>" );
        }
  
  
    }
 
 
 

 

    $("body").on("keyup", "#downpayment , #loanintrest , #loanamount , #period, #per_year", function () {
        change();
    });

    $(function () {
        change();
    });
 
 
  function calculate(amount , term)
  {
   // Standard Mortgage Formula:
   // M = P[i(1+i)n] / [(1+i)n - 1]
   // x = (1+i)n

   var P = amount;
   var i = ($('#loanintrest').val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '') / 100) / 12;
   var n = term;
   var x = Math.pow((1 + i ), n);
   var M = ( P * ((i * x) / (x - 1)) ).toFixed(2);
   return M;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default panel-sidebar-1 filter-checkbox-container">  
    <div class="panel-heading"><h3><?php _l('Mortgage'); ?></h3></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
       
        <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

        <div class="form-group mamount"> 
            <label for="loanamount" class="col-md-12 control-label">{lang_mort_property_price}</label>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="input-group"> 
                    <input   value="4,000" name="loanamount" id="loanamount" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">AED</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--form group ammount end-->

        <div class="form-group mamount"> 
            <label for="loanamount" class="col-md-12 control-label">{lang_mort_downpay}</label>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="input-group"> 
                    <input type="number" value="20" name="downpayment" id="downpayment" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--form group ammount end-->

        <div class="form-group mamount"> 
            <label for="loanamount" class="col-md-12 control-label">{lang_mort_interest}</label>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="input-group"> 
                    <input type="number" value="5" name="loanintrest" id="loanintrest" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--form group ammount end-->

        <div class="form-group mamount"> 
            <label for="loanamount" class="col-md-12 control-label">{lang_mort_year}</label>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="input-group"> 
                    <input type="number" value="5" name="period" id="period" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Year</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--form group ammount end-->
        </div><!--panel body end-->

</br>
 <!-- Chart Area-->
<div class="accordion" id="accordionArea">
 <div class="accordion-group panel">
    <!--result-->
        <div class="accordion-heading accordionize"> <a class="accordion-toggle active" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionArea" href="#mortresult"><i class="fa fa-calculator"></i> Result <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> </a> </div>
            <div id="mortresult" class="accordion-body in collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner"> 
                <p> {lang_mort_month} : <strong > <span style="float:right" id="permonth"> 0 </span> </strong> </p> 
          <p> {lang_mort_downpay} :<strong> <span style="float:right" id="downpament_a"> 0 </span> </strong> </p>
          <p> {lang_mort_tamount} :<strong> <span style="float:right" id="loanamount_total"> 0 </span> </strong> </p>
          <p> {lang_mort_tinterest} :<strong> <span style="float:right" id="total_interest"> 0 </span> </strong> </p>
          <p> {lang_mort_tpay} :<strong> <span style="float:right" id="total_amount"> 0 </span> </strong> </p>
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#disclaimer">{lang_mort_disclaimer}</a>
              <div class="modal fade" id="disclaimer" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <p><font color="red">Warning</font> - The information provided by this tool is for guidance, and does not include all of the details you need to choose a mortgage. Figures given by this calculator do not constitute an offer to lend to you.</p>

     <p>This calculator is designed to give you an indication of the amount that we may be able to lend you on a capital repayment basis. The results shown above are estimates and should be used as guide only. The maximum we would consider lending will depend on your individual situation, the property you are purchasing (e.g. new build), the loan you choose and the amount you wish to borrow. The actual amount will depend on checks that we subsequently undertake and further fees and charges may apply.</p>
     </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default inverted" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
          </div><!--inner end-->
            </div><!--accordion body end-->
        <!--chart-->
        <!--
        <div class="accordion-heading accordionize"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionArea" href="#mortchart"><i class="fa  fa-pie-chart"></i> View Chart <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> </a> </div>
            <div id="mortchart" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner"> 
              <div id="hightcart_container" style=""></div>
          </div>
            </div>-->
            <!--accordion body end-->

<!--
<div class="accordion-heading accordionize"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#monthg" href="#mortmonthly"> Monthly Payment Guide  </a> </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="monthg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">   <table style="width:100%" id="printTable"> 
 <thead style="background:#DEEEFE;width:100%;"> 
 <tr style="width:100%"> 
  <td style=" width:20%">  Month </td> 
  <td style=" width:20%" > Per/Month </td> 
  <td style=" width:20%" > Principle </td> 
  <td style=" width:20%" > Interest </td> 
  <td style=" width:20%"> Balance </td> 
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="tbody"> 
 
 </tbody>
 <thead style="background:#DEEEFE;width:100%;"> 
 <tr style="width:100%"> 
  <td style=" width:20%">  Month </td> 
  <td style=" width:20%" > Per/Month </td> 
  <td style=" width:20%" > Principle </td> 
  <td style=" width:20%" > Interest </td> 
  <td style=" width:20%"> Balance </td> 
 </tr>
 </thead>
 </table> </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default inverted" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

-->
    </div><!--accordion end-->
</div><!--accordion end-->

    
    </div><!--panel panel end-->
```

Comment: Works perfectly , If you don't mind on my result how can I show output with comma(,)? I try to add **.val().replace(/,/g, "");** on my result but they are not working

Comment: To show the number in a specific format, you should try `toLocaleString` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString or `NumberFormat` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **Number()** expects an actual number but since your number isn't pure, it's returning **NAN**.

Adding a simple function in place where you need comma separated digits can solve this problem.

```
function removeCommas(val){
    return val.split(',').join('');
}
```

and

```
var loanamount_total = removeCommas($("#loanamount").val());
```

For instance the above example works fine.