# How can i combine usage of parseFloat and math.trunc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've got a variable with string, lets say it is something like:
const test = '100,71648192';
What i want to do is first change it to number and then use Math.trunc(test*100)/100

I tried parseFloat(test)Math.trunc(test * 100) / 100) but of course it is no working and i know why, but i dont know how i can do it in 1 line

Ty for your answers

Comment: `parseFloat` doesn't recognize commas as decimal separators. `const test = Math.trunc(parseFloat('100,71648192'.replace(',', '.'))*100)/100`

Comment: and [Parsing numbers with a comma decimal separator in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405178/parsing-numbers-with-a-comma-decimal-separator-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you for help, i mean i did have "." not "," initially, but i changed the position of these 2 function and that worked perfectly for me ;)

Comment: Great, glad it helped. Yes, you need to *pass* the result of `parseFloat` to `Math.trunc`, not chain them.